# Display Discord Bot info to NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, discord.js, nuxt.js

So I'm learning NuxtJS and I want to display some info from my Discord bot to the website. Now as I understood I can make a component that gets the information and then call the component. Let me break down the question more.

To get how many users my bot serves I can do `client.users.cache.size` in my normal JS files in node but how do I achieve this in my website? I don't understand how to connect such things really.

And if you can please direct me somewhere that explains more stuff than just the official docs

Comment: You can make an API for your bot using express.js and use it to get that kind of information.

Comment: Indeed @Jakye I made an express API and got the info from that. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an express API that pushes the info that I want and through the VUE app I simply used Axios to get that info.

This  [Mini-series by Traversy Media](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j55fHUJqtyw) helped me A LOT